# Entity Framework 6.2.0 Lazy Loading After Insert

Tags: entity-framework-6

An odd thing happened after an Add

```
context.Activities.Add(activity);
context.SaveChanges();
```

immediately after trying to use the navigation fields

```
CommandId = activity.CommandId;
if (CommandId != 0)
{
    CommandName = activity.Command.CommandName;
}

ActivityCategoryId = activity.ActivityCategoryId;
if (ActivityCategoryId != 0)
{
    ActivityCategoryName = activity.ActivityCategory.Name;
}
```

"Command" is null and "ActivityCategory" is not.  Both were created as part of the "Update Model from Database" and both have public null argument constructors.  Both work on normal queries say to populate a table. The proxies are present for this.  However, after an Add, the proxy for command is not present.

generated code definitions

```
    public virtual ActivityCategory ActivityCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual Command Command { get; set; }
```

If I explicitly "Include", works fine.

```
    public static IList<DAL.Activity> GetActivitiesByCommandI(DAL.MSMTEntities context, int id)
    {
        IList<DAL.Activity> list = context.Activities
            .Include(a => a.Command)
            .FilterActivitiesByCommandId(id)
            .ToList();

        return list;
    }
    public static IQueryable<DAL.Activity> FilterActivitiesByCommandId(this IQueryable<DAL.Activity> query, int id)
    {
        IQueryable<DAL.Activity> result = query
            .Where(act => act.CommandId == id);

        return result;
    }
```

Not sure what to look for next.  Will drill down into the context to looks for clues.  Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: I think it depends on if you just set the CommandId or also set the navigation property of the Command on activity to the one you loaded previously.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this turned out to be a stray entitydatasource in the markup. Why it hacked up on the spatial type, I have not a clue. I downloaded the ef6 from nuget until I can exercise the demon.

Thanks